# Alternate Backround shading of PHP generated HTML <div>'s

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using a PHP script to pull data from an API and generate HTML divs in a Wordpress website.  I'd like to generate alternate 'zebra' shading of the rows being generated on the page but without the ability to add classes etc to the rows, I'm stumped for a way to do this. Any suggestions?

Here is the PHP code:-

```
<?php $schedules = get_schedule_list_upcoming();?>
<?php foreach($schedules->Schedule as $schedule){ ?>
        <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row et_pb_row_4col">
            <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
                    <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $schedule->CourseName; ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
                    <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $schedule->StartDate; ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
                    <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $schedule->CourseLocation; ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
                    <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                        <p>
                        <?php if (($schedule->PlacesLeft) > 0){ ?>
                            <a class="booking" href="<?php echo $schedule->LinkToBookingPage; ?>">Book</a>
                        <?php } else {?>
                            Fully Booked
                        <?php } ?>  
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    ?>
```

Here is the HTML of one row generated by script. Each row generated is identical except for the data within the paragraph tags:-

```
<div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row et_pb_row_4col">
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
<div class="et_pb_text_inner">
<p> JAUPT CRS9179 - Driver Hours and Highway Code</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
<div class="et_pb_text_inner">
<p> 19/10/2018</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
<div class="et_pb_text_inner">
<p>Blackridge</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
<div class="et_pb_text_inner">
<p> <a class="booking" href="/RegisteredGuest/BookingItems.aspx?SchedRef=TS6445992">
Book</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The PHP seems irrelevant here. What does the rendered HTML look like and what CSS have you tried?

Comment: *Without the ability to add classes*?

Comment: Can You paste the output HTML, the page generates. As @j08691 suggested, PHP is really irrelevant here.

Comment: I'm obviously writing one html row in the php script and that is generating the rest of the rows depending on how many data rows it pulls from the API.

Comment: If you want to do it in css only, you need something like `et_pb_row:nth-child(2n) { // yourStyleForEvenRows }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `nth-child` CSS selector. This should work for you:

```
.et_pb_row:nth-child(odd){
    background:#fff;
}
.et_pb_row:nth-child(even){
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first look at not duplicating if possible.

The only difference between:

```
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $schedule->CourseName; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and

```
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $schedule->StartDate; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is the fact that you are changing the inner echo. 
Look at creating a quick function that does that instead, then just keep calling that function with the paragraph text. That way you can easily change the content while keeping formatting consistent.

In regards to your zebra question, you could wrap the row in a section, then target anything within that section, using css of .et_pb_row et_pb_row et_pb_row_4col:nth-child(even) and nth-child(odd) to specifically target.

If you can only edit the HTML code, you could try something like adding a Boolean before the function call, then use an if/else to echo the correct coloring for the row.

So would like

```
<div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row et_pb_row_4col" <?= $white ? "style=background-color: white" : "style=background-color:black" >
```

and then you flip the boolean at the end. Best way would still be adding that if/else into the class echo and adding that class black/white into the css file.

Comment: if you don't understand <?= , it's a shorthand for <?php echo. 
The ? is a ternary operator.